# List FedEx Shipments history using FedEx Web Services

Tags: web-services, fedex

I've been trying to find a way to list all the shipments that were made?.

I know that there's FedEx Insight but the only way to interact is by the Ship Service and the only thing one can do is Add Data for the service on a Shipment.

If the shipments can't be requested, there's a posibility to get a list of Track Id's or the refereces numbers?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a function of FedEx's Web Service.

There's a Track Service but that assumes you know the tracking number or reference value already.

My recommendation would be to look at their EDI solution if you want a comprehensive list of shipments/tracking numbers based on an account.